# Facebook Site Plugin won´t show up (iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, plugins

I tried to create a facebook page plugin iframe with the "dev tools" from facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin?locale=de_DE

My goal is it to create a iframe for this facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/craftbee.Honigbier/

But it will not work. The problem for me is, to figure what is wrong. I have done this for my own facebook page and it works. 
I used my own account and the account of the owner of the facebook page, both accounts won´t show up the iframe.

As you can see, you doesn't see a preview if I use the craftbee.honigbier facebook page.
[image]

If I use my own facebook page you can see a preview:

[image]

So what is wrong here?

Comment: A page with “beer” in the name is most likely access restricted (for having alcohol-related content) ... and as the documentation clearly states, you can not use the page plugin in that case.

Comment: Did facebook some agreements in the last two weeks? Two weeks ago we had a plugin for this page.. :/

Comment: Yes, I think that is a recent change. And apparently it affects other plugins, such as the Like button, as well. (Whether that makes much sense or not, might be a different question. In the past, they used to show the plugin if the user was logged in to Facebook and was allowed to “see” the object.)

Comment: Hm...do you know any workaround to get something similar to this?

Comment: No. You could build it yourself, by getting the post data via API ... but then formatting it is completely your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook had recent changes wich does not allow site plugins for beer and other stuff like that.